# R: Count all previous rows where certain conditions are met for each row

Tags: r, for-loop, count

I'm currently working on my master thesis in the course of online advertising. I have a data set with cookie data of different users and I am aiming to build additional variables, that count the total number of user-website category visits.

This is an illustrative example of how my data set is structured and how the relevant variables of my data set look like:

```
> print(data)
   Imp_ID User_ID  Website.category
1      10      50 Apparel & Jewelry
2      11      51 Apparel & Jewelry
3      12      52        Automotive
4      13      50 Apparel & Jewelry
5      14      51        Automotive
6      15      52        Automotive
7      16      52        Automotive
8      17      51 Apparel & Jewelry
9      18      50 Apparel & Jewelry
10     19      50        Automotive
11     20      51        Automotive
```

The Impression ID is unique, I got 100 different users and 20 different website categories. All impressions are sorted by date and time (datetime variable also available but not necessary for this problem I think)

What I'm trying to do is to count the total number of previous user-website categories impressions for each respective impression event. For instance, I have the website category "apparel & jewelry". When a user has its first impression on a website of the category "apparel & jewelry", the counting variable count_app.jew should be equal to 1, the second time the same user-website category combination appears, the value of this new variable should be 2, and so on.

Thus, I think I need to define something like a for-loop with a counter for each row, that for each row counts all previous observations that meet the predefined conditions (probably somehow with an if statement).

This is my desired result:

```
> print(data2)
   Imp_ID User_ID  Website.category Count_app.jew Count_automotive
1      10      50 Apparel & Jewelry             1                0
2      11      51 Apparel & Jewelry             1                0
3      12      52        Automotive             0                1
4      13      50 Apparel & Jewelry             2                0
5      14      51        Automotive             1                1
6      15      52        Automotive             0                2
7      16      52        Automotive             0                3
8      17      51 Apparel & Jewelry             2                1
9      18      50 Apparel & Jewelry             3                0
10     19      50        Automotive             3                1
11     20      51        Automotive             2                2
```

To explain the logic, count_app.jew is equal to 1 in the first row, since the user with ID=50 has his first impression on a "Apparel&Jewelry" site. In row 2, the user with ID=51 has its first impression on on a "Apparel&Jewelry" site, thus count_app.jew is again equal to 1. In row 3, user with ID=52 visits a website of the category "automotive". Since this user never visited a site of the category "Apparel & Jewelry" before, count_app.jew is equal to 0. Instead, count_automotive is equal to 1. In row 4, count_app.jew is 2, since the user with ID=50 already visited a website of this category for the second time...

Thus, my question is how to create these additional, counting variables.

I hope, the logic behind is clear, and someone knows an appropriate way to solve this problem. Since I do not have a big coding background, I appreciate any help very much!

Comment: Hi Domi, Berbi can you show an example of your data using dput?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
library(dplyr)    
df%>%group_by(User_ID)%>%mutate(Count_app.jew=cumsum(Website.category=="Apparel & Jewelry"),
                                    Count_automotive=cumsum(Website.category=="Automotive"))
```

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Imp_ID = 10:20, User_ID = c(50L, 51L, 52L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 51L), Website.category = c("Apparel & Jewelry", 
"Apparel & Jewelry", "Automotive", "Apparel & Jewelry", "Automotive", 
"Automotive", "Automotive", "Apparel & Jewelry", "Apparel & Jewelry", 
"Automotive", "Automotive")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_df <- by(
  dat, dat$User_ID,
  function(x) within(x, {
      Count_app.jew <- cumsum(Website.category == "Apparel & Jewelry")
      Count_automotive <- cumsum(Website.category == "Automotive")
    })
)

dat <- do.call(rbind, list_df)
dat[order(dat$Imp_ID), ]
```